# Keeping the same numerical order after sorting (Footable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, footable

Standart Footable table. Many columns. 
How to keep the same numerical order after sorting?

Original:

```
id | Book     | Views
---------------------
1  | Book 1   | 3493
2  | Book 2   | 3792
3  | Book 3   | 4022
```

After sorting by Views (DESC):

```
id | Book     | Views
---------------------
3  | Book 3   | 4022
2  | Book 2   | 3792
1  | Book 1   | 3493
```

But i need this:

```
id | Book     | Views
---------------------
1  | Book 3   | 4022
2  | Book 2   | 3792
3  | Book 1   | 3493
```

The goal is that ID must be always 1,2,3 after Sorting (but not after Paging, of course)

Comment: So it's a row number and not an ID, then.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to separate your view from your data a little bit more. I'll illustrate using `Arrays`.

Let's say we have an `arr` Array of 3 objects, containing our books.

`test` and `test2` are both iterating over the same data, but only `test` is displaying in the manor you'd like. This is because instead of using the data's `ID` for display, it is using the index of iteration. Hopefully this can nudge you in the correct direction.

```js
var arr = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Book 1",
  views: 100
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: "Book 2",
  views: 200
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: "Book 3",
  views: 300
}];

function compare(a,b){
  if(a.views > b.views)
    return -1;
  if(b.views > a.views)
    return 1;
  return 0;  
}

arr.sort(compare);

for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  var elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.innerHTML = "id:"+(i+1) + " ";
  elem.innerHTML += "Name: "+arr[i].name + " ";
  elem.innerHTML += "Views: "+arr[i].views;
  console.log(arr[i].id);
  document.getElementById("test").appendChild(elem);
}

for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  var elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.innerHTML = "id:"+arr[i].id + " ";
  elem.innerHTML += "Name: "+arr[i].name + " ";
  elem.innerHTML += "Views: "+arr[i].views;
  console.log(arr[i].id);
  document.getElementById("test2").appendChild(elem);
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="test2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is have each row numbered sequentially, jQuery .each() provides an iteration variable (the `i` in the `function(i)`). The row display is `i+1` because, like most javascript elements, each() is 0-based.

```
$("#mytable tbody tr").each(function(i){
    $(this).find("td:first").text(i+1);
});
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.